# How to determine what is the super class or an interface of an object

Tags: java

say one of my object implements X interface but is returning false when checking with 'instanceof'. How to determine what is the super class or an interface of an object. I am looking for something like

for example:

```
object.getSuperClassORInterface();
```

Comment: If `instanceof X` returns false then your object does *not* implement  the `X` interface. Remember that `null` is `instanceof` nothing, so will always return false. You should post your code, because there is something else wrong if `instanceof` is not doing what you expect.

Comment: If `instanceof` is returning false then your object is **not** implementing that interface. That is, that interface is nowhere in the inheritance hierarchy of your object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use reflection

use [`getSuperClass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSuperclass%28%29)

for example :

```
yourObj.getClass().getSuperClass()
```

Further you can see whether superClass is `Class` or `Interface` using [`isInterface()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInterface%28%29)

Comment: yes it gives the name of the superclass but what if i need the name of the interface.. i used gerInterfaces but just prints adress instead of the name i also tried                 feature.getClass().getInterfaces().getClass().getName() but that does not works as well\

Answer (score 2):

It should return true otherwise the object is null.

Answer (score 2):

May be you are applying instanceof on a null reference variable which will returns false.